# The use of appropriate preposition

Tags: prepositions

Which is the appropriate preposition of the word "Alternative "?

Comment: *Alternative* is both an adjective or noun - presumably you only mean the latter. There's no specific preposition that goes with the noun: use the preposition that suits the context, e.g. *of*, *to*, *for*, *from*, etc. Have you looked up a [dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/alternative)? What do you think? Note that the system has flagged your question for deletion as "low-quality". See [ask] for further guidance and take the [Tour].

Comment: Also, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Answer (score -1):

'To' is the correct preposition to introduce the thing that is being foregone. Of course, 'from' and 'for' could be used in the same sentence, but not with the same meaning, e.g. "an alternative TO bread FOR coeliacs FROM the supermarket."